# How to add dead-line column in mySQL and get the date from angular-node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I have MySQL Database and I work with angular and node.js.

I add a column "deadLine" in my table and make it Datatype: DATETIME.

Now I need help because I new in MySQL I moved on from MongoDB.

What is the best way to insert data to the table from the angular to node.js and then to the database?
Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the available documentation about MySQL, Angular & node. People here can only help with specific problems and won't teach you something you can easily read up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic discussion of the design and architecture of a system. That you have to study a lot. Also, you have a well-designed node js server that responds correctly to client requests. And now in the server section use the modules used to connect to MySQL.

[Angular 7/8 Tutorial: HttpClient POST to Node/Express.js Example](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-tutorial-httpclient-post/)

[How To Post Data From Angular To Node REST API](https://codehandbook.org/post-data-from-angular-to-node-rest-api/)

And search for similar topics.

this module in npm is the best of `mysql` module for working with data base and node js (express framework) server side

[mysql in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)